# want to get country area code from phone number present in mysql db

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having phone number `1212010089` and want to know from which country I'm getting this number.I do have a `table_1` which is having column1 `area_code`where lots of area codes are available and column2 `location` which is having an equivalent location according to that `area_code` the maximum length of `area_code` is 7 in it so please suggest me an appropriate sql query by which I can find the  `location` from that number.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why don't you store the data normalized?

Comment: Be careful, 1212010089 looks like a local number for whichever country your data is stored in by default. An international number would usually start with a plus sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

```
SELECT location
FROM table_1
WHERE '237690000000' LIKE CONCAT(area_code,'%')
AND LENGTH(area_code)=
(SELECT MAX(LENGTH(area_code))
FROM table_1
WHERE '237690000000' LIKE CONCAT(area_code,'%'));
```

See [Demo on DB-SQL Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uCeXbQXg3N4L6E7bGc2QhC/0).

Comment: This is just the first step, but there might be multiple matching rows (e.g. '2','23','237') and now you need to get the best match, usually the row with the longest matching area_code...

Comment: Thank you @dnoeth, I just adjusted the query to take care of that.

Comment: But @cdaiga this query taking too much time when I run this query in crone file and replace phone number with a variable and put this query in a live server. Is there  anyway to decrease the response time.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this:

`SELECT location FROM table_1 WHERE '23769111111' LIKE CONCAT(area_code,'%') ORDER BY LENGTH area_code DESC LIMIT 1`